# Icons on React Native map markers and markers callouts not rendered

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, google-maps-markers

In my app I have the `MapView` with markers rendered conditionally:

```js
renderSpotMarker = (spot, index, myLocation) =>
    <Marker key={index}
      tracksViewChanges={false}
      coordinate={coordsForMarker(spot.GEO_LOCATION)}
      title={spot.NAME}
      onPress={() => this.setLastOpenMarkerLocation(spot)}
      description={spot.DESCRIPTION}>
      <View
        style={[styles.marker, spot.DIFFICULTY === 0 ? { backgroundColor: colors.easy } : (spot.DIFFICULTY === 1 ? { backgroundColor: colors.intermediate } : (spot.DIFFICULTY === 2 ? { backgroundColor: colors.advanced } : { backgroundColor: colors.pro }))]}>
        <Image style={baseStyles.infoIcon24} source={getSpotWaterTypeIc(spot.WATER_TYPE)}/>
      </View>
      <Callout
        tooltip={true}
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SpotInfo', {
          chosenSpot: spot,
          distance: calculateDistance(spot.GEO_LOCATION, myLocation)
      })}>
      <SpotMarkerCallout
        marker={spot}
        userLoc={myLocation}
      />
   </Callout>
</Marker>
```

Based on the spot.DIFFICULTY and spot.WATER_TYPE markers have different colors and images. It is working, but always when the user opens the app some images are not loaded:

[image]

When I refresh the MapView, everything starts to work fine:

[image]

Also when I open marker callout first time, icons in this callout are not rendered:

[image]

After view refresh icons are loaded:

[image]

What is wrong? I was trying to add:

```js
await Asset.loadAsync([
  require('../../assets/images/ic_wave.png'),
  require('../../assets/images/ic_flat.png'),
  require('../../assets/images/windsurfing_icon.png'),
  require('../../assets/images/kitesurfing_icon.png'),
  require('../../assets/images/surfing_icon.png')
])
```

On `componentDidMount()` of this component but it doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using UseStateRef: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-usestateref.
The refObject.current will hold the value.